# BS4 returns [] instead of the wanted HTML tag

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to parse the given website and scrape the table. To me the code looks right. New to python and web parsing

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://delhifightscorona.in/')
doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml-xml')

cases = doc.find_all('div', {"class": "cell"})

print(cases)
```

doing this returns

[]

Comment: what information do you want exactly? There is no `div` called `cell` on the page.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I want to print the total number of cases. I wanted to parse by class, being pretty new I made a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose to print only the cases or the total stats with the date.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://delhifightscorona.in/')
doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
stats = doc.find('div', {"class": "cell medium-5"})
print(stats.text)                 #Print the whole block with dates and the figures
cases = stats.find('h3')
print(cases.text)         #Print the cases only
```

Comment: Thank You!! This was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Done. We need to wait atleast 2 minutes until we can mark correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your parser and the class and there you have it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://delhifightscorona.in/').text, 'html.parser').find('div', {"class": "grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-2"})

print(soup.find("h3").getText())
```

Output:

```
423,831
```